# Subsetting from file names

Tags: csv, unix

I have some files named:

> ```
> Mycase_xxx_x_xxx.csv
> Mycase_xxx_x_xxx_xx_x.csv
> Myanalysis_x_xx_xx_xxx_x_x.csv
> Myattempt_xx_x_xxxx.csv
> ```

I would like the files named in the following way:

> ```
> xxx_x_xxx.csv
> xxx_x_xxx_xx_x.csv
> x_xx_xx_xxx_x_x.csv
> xx_x_xxxx.csv
> ```

In other words I would like (by Unix) to preserve all characters that are present in filenames after the first word.

Can anyone help me please?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved using Perl's `rename` utility, which depending on your system, may be called `rename`, `prename` or `perl-rename`.  On Debian and Ubuntu, it can be installed as follows:

```
sudo apt install rename
```

Note that on some systems, the command `rename` may be Perl's `rename`, while on others it may be `util-linux`'s `rename` and on others it may be GNU `rename`.  These tools are not compatible with each other.

Perl's `rename` tool on Debian and Ubuntu can be used as follows:

```
prename 's/expression/substitution/' filenames...
```

Or to apply to all files in the current directory:

```
prename 's/expression/substitution/' *
```

A useful feature of Perl's `rename` is the ability to use regular expressions (note how the supported syntax is similar to `sed`'s syntax).

In your case, a regular expression to match the prefix of your filenames up to and including the first underscore is as follows:

```
^[^_]*_
```

This can then be substituted with an empty string to remove this part of the filename, resulting in the following command:

```
prename 's/^[^_]*_//' *
```

Before running this command, if you are unsure and would like to test that the files will be renamed how you want them, you can add the flags `-vn` as follows:

```
prename -vn 's/^[^_]*_//' *
```

This will not rename any files and will instead print out a list of the files which will be renamed, like so:

```
$ prename -vn 's/^[^_]*_//' *
Myanalysis_x_xx_xx_xxx_x_x.csv -> x_xx_xx_xxx_x_x.csv
Myattempt_xx_x_xxxx.csv -> xx_x_xxxx.csv
Mycase_xxx_x_xxx.csv -> xxx_x_xxx.csv
Mycase_xxx_x_xxx_xx_x.csv -> xxx_x_xxx_xx_x.csv
```